# Python - is it possible to make a join string with blank column

Tags: python, string, function, join

I am still a new python user and trying to make a longest common subsequence by using python. but I would like to know how to create a loop for comparing the value in row by row first. Here is a sample of the data.

```
row col1  col2  col3  col4   col5  col6 
0   'A'   '11'  'B'           
1   'A'   '11'  'B'   '121'     
2   'A'   '12'  'B'   '123'  '124'   
3   'A'   '13'  'B'   '123'  '124'  '456'
```

here is the sample code of LCS that I am going to adapt.

```
import pandas as pd

df_hier = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")

row1 = df_hier.iloc[1:2, 2:20]
row2 = df_hier.iloc[3:4, 2:20]

    def lcs(s1, s2):
        matrix = [["" for x in range(len(s2))] for x in range(len(s1))]
        for i in range(len(s1)):
            for j in range(len(s2)):
                if s1[i] == s2[j]:
                    if i == 0 or j == 0:
                        matrix[i][j] = s1[i]
                    else:
                        matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][j-1] + s1[i]
                else:
                    matrix[i][j] = max(matrix[i-1][j], matrix[i][j-1], key=len)

        cs = matrix[-1][-1]

        return len(cs), cs

    print(lcs(row1, row2))
```

I have created another function for zipping the LCS which is

```
def lcs_rows(r1, r2):
    pairs = zip(r1.values.flatten(), r2.values.flatten())
    lcss = [lcs(*x) if len(x[0]) and len(x[1]) else (0, 'NaN') for x in pairs]
    nums = [x[0] for x in lcss]
    strs = [x[1] for x in lcss]
    return (sum(nums).join(strs)
```

but result is got the error -> object of type 'float' has no len()

Assumed that

```
the row1 will use 
'A'   '11'  'B'       
and row2
'A'   '12'  'B'   '121'
```

the expecting result will be

(4, 'A1B1')

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the error you get: "object of type 'float' has no len()" occurs because you are trying to perform a function on NaN, in this case, trying to pass NaN to len(). What you want instead is to check whether a value is NaN using the functions pd.isnull() / pd.notnull(). (comparing using "==" also doesn't work).

By the way, it is not a string 'NaN' but a special object you can mention with: "pd.np.nan".

I would suggest to fix the following row:

```
lcss = [lcs(*x) if pd.notnull(x[0]) and pd.notnull(x[1]) else (0, pd.np.nan) for x in pairs]
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, I have followed your suggestion but the Error is appeared at the return value.